# Django, option to login an user using management command

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have commands in `my_app/management/commands/` which need a user that is logged in, more precisely a root user. I need this root for logging (datbase, not python `logging`) purposes.

All I found is that a `request` object is needed from the session to log in a user, like for example in the [django documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in)

**Question:** Is there a way to log in a user when calling a command with `manage.py` without the frontend?

**Update:** Does it make sense at all to somewhat mix OS users with Dashboard users?

Comment: Whats the point of having root access to database logging, when the machine/server has ssh access? SSH will make sure only authorized person has access to it.

Comment: I have an object that stores among other things user and a logging message

Answer (score 1):

This might do the job:

```
from django.test import Client

c = Client()
logged_in = c.login(username='testuser', password='12345')
```

Comment: feels kind of weired using a test module in my production code

Comment: What other choice do you have? As long as it works and if it does not affect the normal code flow then it should fine. Don't you think so?